# Implement a "cancel" button on forms that use databinding and nhibernate

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate, hibernate, data-binding

I use nhibernate to access a mysql database, and I have many -winforms- forms using databinding to modify properties of those objects. There are many –nhibernate- objects created/deleted also during the time those forms are used.

I need to implement a "Cancel" button on those forms.

I can defer the creation/deletion of objects on the database (nhibernate’s Session.Save/Delete) to the moment the form is closing. But I don’t know what to do about the changing of loaded objects’ properties directly by the user (*changed by winforms databinding*) or the adding/removing of objects to the related objects collections.

I’m not a nhibernate expert at all. Is there any way to mark ***a referenced object*** as “not loaded yet”, to force a refresh from the DB the next time it is referenced in any way (collections and properties) ***without losing the reference*** (kind of return the reference to the proxy object to the initial state, before the first load from the DB)?

I’m not a winforms expert at all neither. How can I know which objects where changed through databinding?

Answer (score 1):

I guess a simple approach would be to use [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on your entities and [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) or use a collection that already implements it. Then you can subscribe to those events and, at least know, if they had changed.

In any case this is an aspect of presentation I really would like to hear some opinions on.